# Why does this block of code functions as so?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Most of the main code

```
            driver.get(url)
            usernameelem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,usernameId) 
            usernameelem.send_keys(username) 
            passwordelem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,passwordId)
            passwordelem.send_keys(password)
            passwordelem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            try:
                submitbut = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submitbut.click()
            except:
                submitbut1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submitbut1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) 
            time.sleep(5)
```

The code am not so sure about:

```
            try:
                submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submit.click()
            except:
                submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submit.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

This is the only block of code that works, when i try to make it click on the submit button

Any other method such as

```
                submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submit.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

trying to anticipate the error.. or

```
            try:
                submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submit.click()
            except:
                submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,submit_buttonId)
                submit.click()
```

literally the same thing but clicking

Doesn't work and will always gives "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found"

Am not sure how and why its only workable in such a specific order, the submit button is always visible too, and clickable if manual

Comment: include more of the code you are trying...

Comment: sorry, I didn't think the rest of the code are important, but here's those

Comment: it's possible that when you hit enter on the password field the form is already submitted... at that point it's waiting for a response from the backend, and may have a loading indicator, or simply a change to the button text... i.e. "submitting" We still can't see what your selectors are here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the page it's hard to know for sure but it sounds like the page is loaded and then at least a portion of the page is reloaded. This creates the StaleElementException. The stale element is in `submit`... you've grabbed the element reference from the page and stuffed it into `submit`. The page then reloads so that `submit` is no longer pointing at anything (it's reference is stale). The only fix for this is to get the reference again... that's why you're having to call the same line twice, the first time inside a `try`.

The way to avoid this is to

1. wait for the element to be present
2. wait for it to become stale
3. wait for it to be clickable
4. click it

It sounds like a lot of work but this procedure should remove a lot of the intermittent (and deterministic) failures in these steps. The code would look like

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# define the locator since we're going to use it more than once
submit_locator = (By.XPATH, submit_buttonId)
# wait for the page to load enough that the element exists
submit = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(submit_locator))
# wait for the element to go stale
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(submit))
# now that it's gone stale, now we wait for it to be clickable and click it
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(submit_locator)).click()
```

Comment: Sorry, can't really show the page, since it contains personal information 
I received this error using the code: 
---
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="button" name="BUTTON1" id="N_QRCODE_DRV_BUTTON1" tabindex="21" value="Signin" class="BUTTON" style="width:89px; " onclick="submitAction_win0(document.win0,this.id,event);" title="Upload to Field-by-Field Area"> is not clickable at point (297, 327). Other element would receive the click:
---
By checking using inspect element, am sure there's only one exact element using that xpath

Comment: Also, just checked, it works perfectly fine till the .click() part
Also not sure if its important but the mouse cursor doesn't show the clicking animation when hovering above the button

Comment: Ah I think I fixed it, instead of pressing click, it needs to press "Enter" instead, not sure why it works like so. So ig the problem was a mix of the element being stale and the need to "Enter", thanks for the help!